# How to integrate consecutive time intervals in R

Tags: r

I'm working on a project to integrate consecutive time intervals.

The dataset looks like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 degree=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 start_date=c(as.Date("2016-02-22"),
                              as.Date("2016-03-07"),
                              as.Date("2016-03-21"),
                              as.Date("2016-04-04"),
                              as.Date("2016-04-18"),
                              as.Date("2016-05-02"),
                              as.Date("2016-05-16"),
                              as.Date("2016-06-01"),
                              as.Date("2016-06-13"),
                              as.Date("2016-06-27")),
                 stop_date= c(as.Date("2016-02-22"),
                              as.Date("2016-03-21"),
                              as.Date("2016-04-04"),
                              as.Date("2016-04-18"),
                              as.Date("2016-05-02"),
                              as.Date("2016-05-16"),
                              as.Date("2016-06-01"),
                              as.Date("2016-06-13"),
                              as.Date("2016-06-27"),
                              as.Date("2016-07-25"))
```

And I want to integrate them to one period:

```
df_result <- data.frame(id=c(1,1),
                 degree=c(2,2),
                 start_date=c(as.Date("2016-02-22"),
                              as.Date("2016-03-07")),
                 stop_date= c(as.Date("2016-02-22"),
                              as.Date("2016-07-25")))
```

I've tried the following code:

```
df = df %>%
    group_by(id, degree) %>%
    mutate(
        isConsecutive = lead(start_date) - stop_date == 0,
        isConsecutive = ifelse(
            is.na(isConsecutive) & lag(isConsecutive) == TRUE, FALSE, isConsecutive),
        grp = cumsum(isConsecutive)) %>%
    group_by(id, degree, grp) %>%
    mutate(start_date = min(start_date), stop_date = max(stop_date)) %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-isConsecutive, -grp)
```

My code doesn't work, because it only did the integration once (i.e. only integrate the dates in the first and second rows, but not integrating with the third row)

Comment: can you show expected output.  It didn't work because the `default` values in `lead` and `lag` are NA.  which will remain as NA

Comment: @akrun I also noticed that problem. It worked in my local doc, maybe that's the problem when I create the simplified example? Would it work for lead and lag fxn if I change the dates to days (i.e set the origin date as 2020-01-01)?

Comment: You may change the `default = last(start_date)`

Comment: Thank you, but where should I add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `default` argument in `lead` or `lag` which by default returns `NA` and `NA` in operations returns `NA` unless we make use of `is.na` to correct it.  Here, the fix is simple in `lead` i.e. change the `default` to `last(start_date)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id, degree) %>%
    mutate(
        isConsecutive = lead(start_date, default = last(start_date)) - stop_date == 0,
        isConsecutive = ifelse(
            is.na(isConsecutive) & lag(isConsecutive) == TRUE, FALSE, isConsecutive),
        grp = cumsum(isConsecutive)) %>%
    group_by(id, degree, grp) %>%
    mutate(start_date = min(start_date), stop_date = max(stop_date)) %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-isConsecutive, -grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
     id degree start_date stop_date 
  <dbl>  <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1     1      2 2020-01-01 2020-01-20
```

---

Using the new data, we may use

```
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   group_by(id, degree) %>%
   mutate(grp = rleid(as.numeric(difftime(lead(start_date,
     default = last(start_date)), stop_date, units = 'day')) > 0)) %>% 
   group_by(grp, .add = TRUE) %>%
   summarise(start_date = first(start_date), 
       stop_date = last(stop_date), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id degree   grp start_date stop_date 
  <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <date>     <date>    
1     1      2     1 2016-02-22 2016-02-22
2     1      2     2 2016-03-07 2016-07-25
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! But when I apply the codes to my original dataset, it works for id = 1, but doesn't fully work for other ids. I'm wondering why is that and what would be the possible solution. I'm thinking about adding a while loop for that

Comment: @rachel3765 If you can dput the few data points that shows this behavior then, I can test it (along with the expected output)

Comment: @rachel3765 in this code block, I haven't changed anything except adding the `default` argument

Comment: Thank you! I just edited the original question with the original data.

Comment: @rachel3765 try the update

Comment: Thank you for the update! It solves most of the problem, but still, a few time intervals are still not integrated

Comment: @rachel3765 not clear what kind of pattern those have.  I tried to help you with the ones you provided

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(id, degree) %>% 
    summarise(start_date = min(start_date), stop_date = max(stop_date))
```

```
      id degree start_date stop_date 
  <dbl>  <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1     1      2 2020-01-01 2020-01-20
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the solution. I also tried that before, but since there are other dates that are not necessarily consecutive to this group. Like another set of dates from 2020-04-15 to 2020-06-15. And if I use this method, the interval would be 2020-01-01 to 2020-06-15